# rust sharing read-only reference which is mutated in other places

Tags: rust

How do split a struct into separate read and write objects? I.e. The struct Foo has a member called `bar` which I want to have as a read-only reference in some part of the program (the `readonly` method), and I want to be able to simultaneously mutate `bar` in another part of the program (the `main` function).

I have the following scenario:

```rust
use futures::stream::StreamExt;

struct Foo {
    bar: u8
}

impl Foo {
    fn readonly(self: &Self) -> impl futures::stream::Stream<Item = u8> + '_ {
        futures::stream::iter(0..10).map(|_x| {
            self.bar
        })
    }
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let mut foo = Foo {bar: 123u8};
    let mut stream = foo.readonly();

    let a = stream.next().await;
    println!("a: {:?}", a);

    foo.bar = 132;

    let b = stream.next().await;
    println!("b: {:?}", b);
}
```

which gives the compile error:

```
error[E0506]: cannot assign to `foo.bar` because it is borrowed
  --> src/main.rs:23:5
   |
18 |     let mut stream = foo.readonly();
   |                      -------------- borrow of `foo.bar` occurs here
...
23 |     foo.bar = 132;
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ assignment to borrowed `foo.bar` occurs here
24 |
25 |     let b = stream.next().await;
   |             ------------- borrow later used here
```

I tried to solve this by wrapping the struct in a `Rc<RefCell<_>>`:

```rust
use std::{cell::RefCell, rc::Rc};

use futures::stream::StreamExt;

struct Foo {
    bar: u8
}

impl Foo {
    fn readonly<'a>(self: &'a Self) -> impl futures::stream::Stream<Item = u8> + 'a {
        futures::stream::iter(0..10).map(|_x| {
            self.bar
        })
    }
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let foo = Rc::new(RefCell::new(Foo {bar: 123u8}));
    let foo_cloned = foo.clone();
    let foo_borrowed = foo_cloned.borrow();
    let mut stream = foo_borrowed.readonly();

    let a = stream.next().await;
    println!("a: {:?}", a);

    foo.borrow_mut().bar = 0u8;

    let b = stream.next().await;
    println!("b: {:?}", b);
}
```

but this fails at runtime with:

```
a: Some(123)
thread 'main' panicked at 'already borrowed: BorrowMutError', src/main.rs:28:9
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
```

If I instead use unsafe code it works:

```rust
#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let foo = Rc::new(RefCell::new(Foo {bar: 123u8}));
    let foo_cloned = foo.clone();
    let foo_borrowed = foo_cloned.borrow();
    let mut stream = foo_borrowed.readonly();

    let a = stream.next().await;
    println!("a: {:?}", a);

    unsafe {
        (*foo.as_ptr()).bar = 0u8;
    }

    let b = stream.next().await;
    println!("b: {:?}", b);
}
```

output:

```
a: Some(123)
b: Some(0)
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021)

is there a better, more specialized way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost got it, but you have to wrap only the part you care about in a `Cell` or `RefCell`, not the whole struct:

```rust
use std::cell::Cell;

use futures::stream::StreamExt;

struct Foo {
    bar: Cell<u8>,
}

impl Foo {
    fn readonly(self: &Self) -> impl futures::stream::Stream<Item = u8> + '_ {
        futures::stream::iter(0..10).map(|_x| {
            self.bar.get()
        })
    }
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let mut foo = Foo {bar: Cell::new(123u8)};
    let mut stream = foo.readonly();

    let a = stream.next().await;
    println!("a: {:?}", a);

    foo.bar.set(132);

    let b = stream.next().await;
    println!("b: {:?}", b);
}
```